# SparkContext fails to start with master set to "Yarn"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Apache Spark, trying to run SparkContext inside a Scala API (Play framework). When I set Spark master to "local" it works fine, however, when I set master to "YARN" it throws an exception:

```
[SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.]
```

when I check the logs for container, I get the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher
```

if I run  `spark-shell --master yarn`  it runs SparkContext without any problems.

Here is my code:

```
 val sparkS = SparkSession.builder
  .config("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "false")
  .config("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
  .config("spark.driver.memory", "3g")
  .config("spark.rpc.message.maxSize", "2047")
  .config("SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH", "/usr/local/spark/jars/*")
  .config("spark.yarn.archive", "hdfs://localhost:54310/spark-libs.jar")
  .config("spark.yarn.jars", "/usr/local/spark/jars/*")
  .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers=\"one two three\"")
  .config("spark.executor.extraLibraryPath", "/usr/local/hadoop-2.8.5/lib/native:/usr/local/hadoop-2.8.5/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64")
  .config("HADOOP_CONF_DIR", "/usr/local/hadoop-2.8.5/etc/hadoop")
  .config("spark.yarn.am.waitTime", "1d")
  .master("yarn").getOrCreate
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will have to mention the main class when submitting the spark jar.Below is the format

```
  ./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I am not using spark-submit. Is it possible to run the code directly? I am building a web API, and I want this API to perform queries through Spark. What is the best way to achieve this?